# Constructing a Binary Tree with a given preorder

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to construct a binary tree with **only** given a `preorder`.

My approach is to go through the array and check each element. If the element is an operator `(+, -, *, /)`, then I set the current element as root and set `root.left` and `root.right` as `array[i + 1]` and `array[i + 2]`, respectively.

If the current element is **not** an operator, I print out the element.

I thought if I do this recursively, I will be able to construct a binary tree. However, I am getting some errors and I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

This is my code so far:

```
class Node {
    Object data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(Object item) {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

public class MyTree {
    Node root;

    public MyTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    private static String[] array;
    private static MyTree01 tree = new MyTree();

    static void createBT(Node node) {

        if (array == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == "-" || array[i] == "+" || array[i] == "*" || array[i] == "/") {
                tree.root = new Node(array[i]);
                tree.root.left = new Node(array[i + 1]);
                tree.root.right = new Node(array[i + 2]);

                createBT(tree.root.left);
                createBT(tree.root.right);

            } else {
                System.out.println(node.data + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    void createBT() {
        createBT(root);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        array = new String[] {"-", "-", "x", "y", "*", "+", "s", "t", "/", "x", "s"};
        createBT(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Again, I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. I need some guidance, and please let me know if my approach is completely wrong!

Comment: The approach is incorrect since you start the array again from the start, i.e, `int i = 0;` in the for loop needs to change.

Comment: Also, the way you assign nodes is also incorrect. The expression that the BT represents is `(x-y) - (s + t ) * ( x / s )`

Comment: Hmm.. I now see the problem. Do you have any suggestions to deal with for loop problem? I cannot think of anything as of now..

Comment: FYI, the correct name for such a tree is an [*abstract syntax tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), or AST for short. Searching for that term will yield far more relevant help than searching for “binary tree”.

Comment: When you say, "given the preorder," do you mean that you're given a mathematical expression in prefix notation, and you want to create the corresponding expression tree? A sample of the input would be helpful.

Comment: @Bohemian I see. Thank you for letting me know. I will look into it.

Comment: @Jims Mischel an example of an input I want to work with would be something like “—xy*+st/xs”. Just a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
class Node {
    String data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(String item) {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
public class Algo{   
    public Node createBT(String[] arr){
       Node root = null;
       if(arr == null || arr.length == 0) return root;// to handle edge case of empty lists.
       Stack<Node> st = new Stack<>();

       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            Node new_node = new Node(arr[i]);
            attachChildToParent(st,new_node);// attach child to it's parent(which will be most recent/top in the stack)
            if(root == null) root = new_node;
            if(isOperator(arr[i])){                                                  
                st.push(new_node); // only push operators to stack as operands will always be leaf nodes
            }
       }

       return root;
    }    

    private boolean isOperator(String s){
        return s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("*") || s.equals("/");
    }

    private void attachChildToParent(Stack<Node> st,Node child_node){
        if(st.isEmpty()) return;
        Node parent_node = st.peek();
        if(parent_node.left == null){
            parent_node.left = child_node;
        }else{
            parent_node.right = child_node;
            st.pop(); // no need to keep parent in the stack anymore since we assigned nodes on both ends(left and right) 
        }
    }

    private void preorder(Node root,List<String> nodes){
        if(root == null) return;
        nodes.add(root.data);
        preorder(root.left,nodes);
        preorder(root.right,nodes);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] test_cases = new String[][]{
            {"-", "-", "x", "y", "*", "+", "s", "t", "/", "x", "s"},
            {"/","-", "-", "x", "y", "*", "+", "s", "t", "/", "x", "s","t"},
            {"y"}
        };        
        Algo obj = new Algo();
        for(int i=0;i<test_cases.length;++i){
            Node root = obj.createBT(test_cases[i]);
            List<String> preorder_result = new ArrayList<>();
            obj.preorder(root,preorder_result);
            boolean expected_success = true;
            for(int j=0;j<test_cases[i].length;++j){
                if(!test_cases[i][j].equals(preorder_result.get(j))){
                    expected_success = false;
                    break;
                }                
            }
            System.out.println("Test Case: " + Arrays.toString(test_cases[i]));
            if(expected_success){
                System.out.println("Result: ok");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Result: not ok");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Test Case: [-, -, x, y, *, +, s, t, /, x, s]
Result: ok
Test Case: [/, -, -, x, y, *, +, s, t, /, x, s, t]
Result: ok
Test Case: [y]
Result: ok
```

**Explanation:**

- Understand that operands(variables) **will always be leaf nodes**. Root node of the tree can also be a leaf node(arises when there is only 1 operand in the entire expression).
- Now, since you mentioned **preorder** traversal of the BT is given, we follow a **left-first approach** and use a **stack** to create our binary tree.
- Whenever, we see an operand(+,-,*,/), we create a new node(obviously) and push it to the stack. The reason why we push it is because for the entire expression to make sense, we still need to gather it's right sub tree(which will come in the future values of the array).
- By **left-first approach** I mean that, we fetch the parent of the current node from the stack(if it's not empty) and check if it's left sub tree is null, if yes, assign the child there, else assign it to the right. We do this since the traversal given to you is **preorder**.
- We again push this `new_node` if it's an `operator` to the stack to accommodate future variables as it's leaf nodes. For example, `{"-,"-","x","y"}`. So, the tree for the it will look like,

  ```
      -
     /  
    -
   / \
  x   y
  ```
- In the above expression, `y` got assigned to it's parent `-` and then we remove the most recent `-` from the stack since we no longer need it.
- Now, what remains in the stack is just `-`, which is the root node. Then we move on to further values in the array and decide for them as described above.

Comment: Aha, I see.. Thank you so much. I didn't think of using a stack before. I have a small question here though: How would I be able to print out `obj`??

Comment: @IsaacSeo `obj` is just an object of `Algo` class. Why do you want to print it? Also, what do you mean by `printing` **obj**?

Comment: I wanted to print it because I am assuming that `obj` is the `tree` made from the given `preorder` (Please tell me if I am wrong). Will there be a case that I might want to see what `obj` is? What I mean by **printing** is to see what's inside `obj`.

Comment: @IsaacSeo No `obj` does not have the tree in it. You can find the tree created inside `root` variable created in this line `Node root = obj.createBT(test_cases[i]);`

Comment: Aha, I see. I get it now. Thank you! Helped me a lot :)

Comment: @IsaacSeo Glad to help :)